# How to turn minutes into years and days?

Tags: java

In the textbook it explains how to convert seconds into minutes with how many seconds remain but the question I have is as follows.

> Write a program that prompts the user to enter the minutes (e.g., 1
>   billion), and displays the number of years and days for the minutes.
>   For simplicity, assume a year has 365 days. Here is an example.
>
> ```
> Enter the number of minutes: 100000000
> 100000000 minutes is approximately 1902 years and 214 days.
> ```

What I currently have is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ch2_Exercise2_7 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Prompt user for number of minutes
    System.out.println("Enter the number of minutes:");
    int minutes = input.nextInt();

     // Number of minutes in a year
    int year = minutes / 525600;
    int day = minutes / 1440;
    int remainingMinutes = day % 525600;


    System.out.println(minutes + " minutes is " + year + " years and "  +  remainingMinutes + " days ");
    }

   }
```

With what I have it isn't giving me the remaining minutes into days. For example, if I put in 525600 minutes it gives me 1 year and 365 days when it should just be 1 year.

I'm using Java Eclipse. Any help would be greatly appreciated! My apologies in advance if I post the code incorrectly.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: This should be very basic assuming you know your conversions

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What I understand you are trying to do is: Accept a number from the user, show the number of days and hours left to achieve that point in time. Is that correct? If so, you will have to convert the minutes into days and hours, which you are already doing. So what is the point of your question??

Comment: Use JodaTime or Java 8s Time API

Comment: Is the above a question or a statement.

Comment: With what I have it isn't giving me the remaining minutes into days. If I put in 525600 minutes it gives me 1 year and 365 days when it should just be 1 year.

Comment: That's because you took the number of total minutes and divided by 1440. You should have taken the remainder and divided.

Comment: @Michael that is because you are converting it to both years and days at the same time.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You screwed up a bit over here:

```
// Number of minutes in a year
int year = minutes / 525600;
int day = minutes / 1440;
int remainingMinutes = day % 525600;
```

You took the total number of minutes and divided by 1440, so the number of days you got was wrong. You should have taken the remainder and then divided by 1440.

Another thing was in your print statement. You wrote the number of minutes left after one year as the number of days.

This should work:

```
// Number of minutes in a year
int year = minutes / 525600;
int remainingMinutes = minutes % 525600;
int day = remainingMinutes / 1440;

System.out.println(minutes + " minutes is approximately " + year + " years and " + day + " days.");
```

Answer (score 1):

My main method is separate:

```
public class MinutesToYearsDaysCalculator {
    
        public static void printYearsAndDays(long minutes) {
            double days = minutes / 60 / 24;
            double years = days / 365;
            double remainingDays = days % 365;
    
            System.out.println((minutes < 0 ? "Invalid Value" : minutes + " min = " + (int) years + " y and " + (int) remainingDays + " d"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int mins,hours,remainingDays,days,years;

cout << "Enter minutes:";
cin >> mins;

hours = mins/60;
days = hours/24;
years = days/365;

remainingDays = days % 365;

cout << years << " years " << remainingDays << " days " << endl;

return 0;
```

Comment: please reformat code to make it easier to copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MinutesToYearsDaysCalculator {
    public static void printYearsAndDays(long minutes)
    {
        if(minutes<0) System.out.println("Invalid Value");
        else
        {
            long hours = minutes/60;
            long day   = hours/24;
            long years = day/365;
            long remainingDays = day % 365;
            System.out.println(minutes +" min = "+ years+" y and "+remainingDays +" d");
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prog13 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter The Minute");
    int min=sc.nextInt();
    int year= min/(365*24*60);
    int remaining_min=(min%24*60*60);
    int day=remaining_min/24*60;
    
    System.out.println( min + " " + " Minutes is approximately:"+ year + " " +"year"+ ' '+ day + "Day" );
     

}
```

}

Comment: please include some description to your answer and format all code

Answer (score 0):

hello you can use this result

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class MinToYearsAndDays {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("number of minutes:");
            int minutes = input.nextInt();
            int year = minutes / 525600;
            int remainingMinutes = minutes % 525600;
            int day = (remainingMinutes / 1440);
    
            System.out.println(minutes + " minutes is approximately " + year + " years and " + day + " days ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should at lease describe what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Mints_to_days_years {

// Given some numbers of minutes calculate the number of days and years
// from the given minutes.
// 1hr = 60 minutes
// 1 day = 24 hours
// 1 year = 365 days

public static void find_days_years(long minutes) {
    if(minutes < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number of minutes.");
    }
    // to find the number of years, divide the nminutes by total numbers of minutes in a year.
    long years = minutes / (60 * 24 * 365);
    
    // then find the remainder minutes that does not goes exactly into year
    long years_remainder = minutes % (60 * 24 * 365);

    // divide the remainder by number of minutes in a day to find the numbers of days
    long days = years_remainder / (60 * 24);
    System.out.println(minutes + " mints = " + years + " yrs and " + days + " days.");
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    find_days_years(525600);
    find_days_years(1051200);
    find_days_years(561600);
}
}
```